# Understanding Optionals in Swift when creating AVAudioPlayers

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I'm new to Swift, making the transition from Obj-C and not having much experience of other languages.

I've read up about optionals, understand the overall premise and sort of get why they might be a good thing. But I'm struggling to grasp how they work in practice. The following code works fine, but I'd like an explanation of why it is the way it is.

I'm making an app that plays audio from a file using `AVAudioPlayer`. I'm firstly creating an instance of the AVAudioPlayer class:

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?
```

Q1. Why does this have to be an optional type? Presumably because it has yet to be initialised / has yet to contain any data?

The code I am then using to load audio into `player` is as follows:

```
guard let audioFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample-audio", ofType: "caf") else {
    print("sample-audio.caf does not exist in the bundle.")
    return
}
let audioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: audioFile)
do {
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
    player?.delegate = self
    player?.prepareToPlay()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Q2. If `player` is an optional type, why is the `?` symbol omitted here when assigning the URL to it using the try/catch statement?

Q3. If an optional is like a "box you have to unwrap", containing either a value or nothing/nil, then how is it possible to directly call properties and functions on it such as `player?.delegate` and `player?.prepareToPlay()`

Sorry, three questions, but interrelated…

Answers will really help me get my head around this fundamental aspect of Swift.

Comment: It's not clear why you believe this needs to be an optional type. As long as it has a non-nil value before the end of its declaration scope (`init` if this is a property), it doesn't have to be optional. If there's some point outside its declaration scope where it has no value, then you need an optional value to hold the "it has no value" state.

Comment: Keep in mind that none of your questions appear to be specific to AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Regarding Q2, it's not clear which `?` you mean here. There is no place where an URL is assigned to it (you couldn't assign an URL to it; it's a AVPlayer). For Q3, you're not directly calling properties and functions. You're using `?.`, which is the "box you have to unwrap" step you mention.

Comment: maddy, yes, but I wondered if my questions were specific to this context. Perhaps title should have been less specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: It doesn't have to be optional, but yes it hasn't been initialized at that point. You have several options: `?` and initialize it when you need to, `!` and you must initialize it before you try to use it or else your program will crash, or initialize it at the point of declaration. What you do depends entirely on the context. In this particular case it's probably good practice to have it optional.

Q2: There's no need for a `?` on that line. Where would it go? The compiler knows `player` is optional, and nothing is being unwrapped, you're just assigning a value to your optional variable.

Q3: [Optional chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) allows you to call things on optional objects without actually unwrapping them first. It just implicitly does that work for you so your code can be much more concise. If the object is nil nothing happens, otherwise it will run the call. Note that it cascades the optionality down, so even if the property etc is not optional, it will inherit the optionality in a statement like that.

Comment: Q1. Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: Q2. Why not  player? = try AVAudioPlayer()

Comment: What would that do? The compiler already knows it's an optional value. You're not unwrapping anything.

Comment: So once 'player' has been established as an optional type at declaration, you no longer need to keep using the ? symbol when referring to it. But '?.' is used to enact optional chaining... think the clouds are parting...

Comment: Yea pretty much. The compiler forces you to pay attention to optional values when you're accessing things on them, since it doesn't want you trying to access memory that doesn't have anything in it. But to assign a value to what your optional `var` is pointing to does not require a `?`.

Comment: Note `?` is used a few different ways in Swift. There's still the ternary operator, which has nothing to do with optionals, there's the [nil coalescing operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html) `??`, you can use it with `as?` for casting, and `try?` to skip over the error handling when necessary. (The last two also work with `!` but be careful not to overuse forced unwraps as it defeats the purpose of these Swift features.) And you can declare types to be optional like `var player: AVAudioPlayer?` as you have above.

Comment: Phew! And I thought Swift was supposed to be quick to pick up. In reality this creates an initial hurdle. Thanks for the clear answers though, really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`do-catch` process always related to optional suppose you declared the player like this

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer!
```

and the do block fails , it's may be other parts of the VC uses player , so once it's referenced the app will crash because of **!** , that's why it's declared **?**

//

what does it means **?** here

```
player?.delegate = self
```

simply if player is nil the statement will not run , and if not then the delegate will be set

//

You don't do

```
player? = //////
```

because it meaningless and will cause the statement not to be run , as the key behind it is calling properties and methods of player if it's not nil and here there is no thing to attach or call

Answer (score 0):

A1: Yes *because it has yet to be initialised / has yet to contain any data*. But in this case – the property is going to be initialized always before being used – you can declare it as implicit unwrapped optional `AVAudioPlayer!` and get rid of the question marks. In this particular case you can even use a non-optional with the default initializer of `AVAudioPlayer` but this does not work with any type.

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer()
```

A2: You can assign both non-optional and optional values to an optional variable. The `?` is only relevant when you are sending messages from the variable.

A3: `player?.delegate = self` is called `Optional chaining`. If `player` is `nil` then the rest of the line is being ignored.

---

Since the audio file must exist because the application bundle is not mutable at runtime you can omit all `guard`s and `catch`s. The code must not crash. If it does you made a **design** mistake.

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer()

let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample-audio", withExtension: "caf")!
player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
player.prepareToPlay()
```

Comment: "you can omit all guards and catchs. The code must not crash. If it does you made a design mistake". Really? Doesn't that defeat the point of having these features in Swift?

Comment: No, there is more than black and white. If a certain condition cannot be changed at runtime (e.g. the existence of `AppDelegate`, immutable files in the bundle, custom table view cell identifiers,  particular extracted `DateComponents` etc.) force unwrapping is safe.